# Suggestions on improving NER recall in SpaCy 2.2.3

Tags: spacy

I am looking for suggestions on improving recall (potentially via hyperparameters or a different optimizer) in custom NER training in SpaCy.

I am currently working on training SpaCy 2.2.3 to extract US stock tickers as a custom entity type.  I have trained on ~40K labeled news stories that have tickers identified in them, and have tried the default Adam optimizer with default hyperparameters.

The stats after training for 30 epochs (although I've found them to also be similar with 20 epochs) are as follows on the test set:
f1: 0.8024804229439122
precision: 0.9800634345265066
recall: 0.6793798936575954

I'm pretty happy with the precision, but am looking for suggestions on improving the recall.

Any suggestions for tuning the default hyperparameters, optimizer, or training approach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can't improve recall specifically in spacy but you can do a workaround by monitoring the F1 score. Save the model with a high F1 score on the validation dataset. This way you will have good precision, recall.

Since precision and recall are mutually exclusive, hence your precision might be compromised but you will have a better ner than the current one.

For more reference: https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/3965 ,
https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/3706